# Splunk: lowercase values before idexing

Tags: indexing, formatting, splunk

### Context

I created an [indexed field](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.0/Data/Configureindex-timefieldextraction) for two different data sources. Here is the **props.conf**

```
[source::...stdOutErr*.log]
...
TRANSFORMS-projectName = tjs-projectName

[source::...resuming*.log]
...
TRANSFORMS-projectName = tjs-projectName-resuming
```

Because the `projectName` fields appears in logs structured in a very different ways, I am using two different **REGEX**. Here is the **transforms.conf**.

```
[tjs-projectName]
REGEX = ^\[[A-Z]{4,5}\s?\]:\s(?<projectName>\w+)
FORMAT = projectName::$1
WRITE_META = true

[tjs-projectName-resuming]
REGEX = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","(?<projectName>\w+)"
FORMAT = projectName::$1
WRITE_META = true
```

Last, this is for indexing
**fields.conf**

```
[tjs-projectName]
INDEXED = true

[tjs-projectName-resuming]
INDEXED = true
```

### Issue

Values for `projectName` appears in **CAPITAL** in `resuming*.log` but in **lowercase** in `stdOutErr*.log`. I would like to **uniform** things **before indexing**. From what I read, I should use `SEDCMD` in **props.conf** but my attempts where not quite successful, either

- because I s**k at perl styled regex used by `SEDCMD`
- because this seems illogical and should be handled in **transforms.conf**

```
[source::...resuming*.log]
SEDCMD-projectName = s/"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","[^"]*","\(?<projectName>\w+\)"/\L\1\g
TRANSFORMS-projectName = tjs-projectName-resuming
```

Is there a more direct approach (something easier I could use in **transforms.conf**) or should I stick to `SEDCMD`?

Answer (score 1):

Nice thing with *SEDCMD* is that you can test expressions based on sample data using *sed* mode for *rex* command and synthetic data similar to your actual log data

Once you see it's working you can pick the string and add it in the props.conf on your indexers.

```
SEDCMD-upper2lower = s/[aA]/a/g s/[bB]/b/g s/[cC]/c/g s/[dD]/d/g s/[eE]/e/g s/[fF]/f/g s/[gG]/g/g s/[hH]/h/g s/[iI]/i/g s/j/[jJ]/g s/[kK]/k/g s/[lL]/l/g s/[mM]/m/g s/[nN]/n/g s/[oO]/o/g s/[pP]/p/g s/[qQ]/q/g s/[rR]/r/g s/[sS]/s/g s/[tT]/t/g s/[uU]/u/g s/[vV]/v/g s/[wW]/w/g s/[xX]/x/g s/[yY]/y/g s/[zZ]/z/g
```

Converting all projectNames to lowercase

```
| makeresults

 | eval projectName="alpha BETA gamma DELTA"
 | makemv delim=" " projectName 
 | mvexpand projectName
 | eval projectName_orig=projectName
 | rex field=projectName mode=sed "s/[aA]/a/g s/[bB]/b/g s/[cC]/c/g s/[dD]/d/g s/[eE]/e/g s/[fF]/f/g s/[gG]/g/g s/[hH]/h/g s/[iI]/i/g s/j/[jJ]/g s/[kK]/k/g s/[lL]/l/g s/[mM]/m/g s/[nN]/n/g s/[oO]/o/g s/[pP]/p/g s/[qQ]/q/g s/[rR]/r/g s/[sS]/s/g s/[tT]/t/g s/[uU]/u/g s/[vV]/v/g s/[wW]/w/g s/[xX]/x/g s/[yY]/y/g s/[zZ]/z/g"
 
 |table projectName_orig projectName
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to do this **before indexing**: this looks like a search head tweek.

Comment: Say I get a functional `SEDCMD`, how can I be sure that inserting it before `TRANSFORMS-projectName` will work

Comment: That's a method to test your SEDCMD. After you see it's doing what you need it to, the SEDCMD expression can be applied to events at index time.